# Selection Glitch

Tags: selection-tools

When I try to select the faces of my sphere with <kbd>C</kbd> the selection slowly becomes random.

[image: Look this screen capture]

Furthermore, in solid view in edit mode, when adding a new cube, it looks like this picture, with all faces divided by triangles and strange borders!?!

[image: Cube visualization]

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem, related with you driver of video. Enter in Blender User Preference <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and try with different configurations, in **Selection** and **Window Draw Method**, to fix it.

[image: Bug selection Blender Fixed Lionel Bino]

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but still not work, in my user preferences this setting is already set to "automatic"!

Maybe the problem could be related at my system, i use blender in Fedora 24 with gnome 3. my Graphics card is Quadro 580FX with compatibility driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem might be that you have set the number in the image below too low , try increasing it it may fix your problem. Hit N while your mouse is in 3d view to bring up those options[image]